Congruence $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3\equiv0 \pmod p$ has a non zero solution for all primes
How to prove that the congruence $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3\equiv0 \pmod p$ has a non-zero solution for all primes $p$?
I tried using a theorem that estimates the number of solutions that such a congruence may have. If $N$ is the number of solutions, then $|N-p^2|\leq C(p-1)p^{\frac{1}{2}}$, where $C$ is either $0$, or $8$. I assumed that $N=1$ (the zero solution is the only solution), and tried to get a contradiction.
The case $C=0$ was easy. For $C=8$, I came to the conclusion that I had to check that the congruence has a non-zero solution for all primes up to $62$.
Is there an easier solution?

We can easily check that $x=y=z=p$ is always a Solution !

@Prem  All joking aside, the question specifically asked, and included in every editing, a non-zero solution.

That is a non-zero Solution , while $x=y=z=0$ is what is literally be excluded , @fleablood , I guess non-trivial Solution is the more suitable wording here !

This is a very known example proved the first by Selmer.  There are solutions for all prime but not over $\mathbb Z$. (This is not the case for quadratic according to a classic theorem).

@Prem I guess OP is looking for solutions mod $p$, in which case $(p,p,p)=(0,0,0)$ is a zero solution.

Modular arithmetic is in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and not in $\mathbb Z$.   $p\equiv 0$ so that is literally and accurately not a non-zero solution.  There is no need for more "suitable" wording.  Indeed treating elements as though they are literal integers rather residue classes is not "suitable"

@Prem The wording is clear. The question explicitly states "mod p". There is no ambiguity. Looking at your profile, you may not yet have been exposed to modular arithmetic. In modular arithmetic (mod p) every number is equal to its remainder when divided by p. Therefore, $p=0$ mod p.

Celebrity of this example and required proof here: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/selmerexample.pdf

See also here.
